# two functions for one onsubmit

Tags: html, function, onsubmit

I am trying to get two function to work on one onsubmit, I made this code:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm1(); return  validateForm2()">
```

but this makes validateForm1() function just work and validateForm2() doesn't ,

how to make both functions work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return 2 times in a row. First return will complete the logic of your function.
Instead you should use something like this:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
myElement.onsubmit = function(){
   validateForm1();
   validateForm2();
}
```

Also you shouldn't use inline javascript the way you do this right now. I think you might find [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) useful.

Comment: and what should I write on the form ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have to functions returning at this point. You could use the result of both in a combined call:

```
function validateBoth() {
    return validateForm1() && validateForm2();
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but still make just the first function works.

Comment: Depending on the logic it could be validateForm1() || validateForm2(). That way both functions will be called.